# How to perform an action once Mathjax loaded completely?

Tags: mathjax

I'm developing an online exam application.The questions contain just text or equations or both text and equations. The equations are displayed using Mathjax.There is a timer on the page. I want to start the timer only when the Mathjax equations are loaded completely.If the question doesn't contains any equation then the timer has to be started without waiting for Mathjax.How can this be done? The application is developed in PHP.

Comment: This is not really a (La)TeX question: it's about web programming. As such, I'm afraid it looks off-topic for us, and possibly more suited to the StackOverflow main site.

Comment: Sorry.I'll post in StackOverflow.

Comment: See http://www.mathjax.org/docs/2.0/signals.html

Comment: Push your action onto the MathJax.Hub command queue.  See http://www.mathjax.org/docs/2.0/queues.html#the-mathjax-processing-queue